# Struggling to process JSON with MS-Flow - Power Automate

Tags: json, power-automate

I have a heavily nested JSON packet, containing arrays of arrays, and at the end of the chain there is invariably a key-value pair named: "id:" and "value:".

In the Power Automate interface, available objects, fields, etc are listed without any context so I just see a long list of "id" keys available without any indication, tooltip or other help to distinguish where they actually originate in the JSON structure.

At least, I haven't found a way to do this, so it is very frustrating just having to pick one at random, then "peek at code" to see if "by chance" I have picked correctly... which invariably I have not.

The PowerAutomate interface is SO frustrating for a tool that is so useful!

Does anyone out there know how to resolve this, or indeed, if it is not a problem, but I am doing it all wrong!?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Currently we can't distinguish them(from the UI) indeed, we can just open the peek code as you mentioned. But the list of "id" keys should be sort by the order in your json data. You can feedback the problem in this [page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps)

Comment: Thanks Hury! Not a solution but at least some useful information that will help me a bit.